# Is there a performance difference between using local drives and equivalent UNC paths?

Tags: windows, performance, unc

These two paths are equal:

> \\myhostname\c$\temp
>   c:\temp

Is there a performance difference between them? Specifically, long sequential reads and writes.

Answer (score 5):

There is a minimal network enumeration and name resolution but it's not per transaction.  There would be no noticable performance difference between the 2.